# What are bots trying to do by hitting my website?

Tags: ip, bots

At the end of each month my company sends out web statistics to show who was accessing our website, where they were from, their IP addresses, etc. Our site is very specific to my region of the United States, yet a lot of our traffic comes from Ukraine, France, Russia, and other countries that shouldn't really interested in our site. The web developers here say they are just "bots" looking for sites to hack.

What are these bots? And what are they really looking for? If they found out they could hack our site, what would that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look for known vulnerabilities, e.g. by attempting to fetch the admin pages for a popular blog package which is known to be vulnerable in some old versions. When they find a vulnerable site, they have a script (which typically they don't even understand; hence, "script kiddies") which exploits the vulnerability and gives them a root shell. From there on, anything is possible, but again, typically, spam, malware, leveraging your network for anonymization and bandwith e.g. for further attacks.